# I'm trying to set program compatibility with windows 10

Tags: windows, properties, configuration

I'm trying to set program compatibility with windows 10. The property tab for doing this doesn't show up.

I've checked the registry key. The AppCompat key is not there which means that the tab should be displayed.

I've also checked the setting in the group policy editor. It is set to "Not Configured" which means that the tab should be displayed.

Everything that I have found online indicates that I should see the tab.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The compatibility shims are only for end-users, not something developers should set. If you are a developer you should fix your app instead. If you are a end-user then you are asking on the wrong website, try SuperUser...

Comment: That was a less than useful comment. I am a developer trying to get an old driver to work with a newer version of the OS, hopefully without changes as no one is left here who remembers the code.

Comment: I was just echoing https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100311-00/?p=14643# | Anyway, is this a .exe or something else? Have you tried renaming it? Tried another machine? You did not give us much to go on...

Comment: I tried several files, both .exe and .sav. The tab does not show up. Presumably, there is something wrong with the settings, but, as I said originally, they all seem to be set correctly.